# In Delphi is there a way to backup and restore a postgres database using FireDAC or cmd

Tags: postgresql, delphi, backup, restore

Is there a way to create postgresql backup/restore database with Delphi application

Is there a way to do this with Delphi?

```
var
    program_path: string;
begin
program_path:= c:/myprogram.exe

ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', PChar('/C pg_dump....;
```

Comment: dBeaver is free, can be [controller by command line](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Command-Line) and allows connection to many different databases.  For a DIY solution, there are both [free and commercial options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956483/open-source-component-for-postgresql)

Comment: thanks but i create a delphi application i like to create a postgresql backup with a button in my application

Comment: you do give example of running an external program... in any case, [Zeos](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) does mention Postgresql.